# Django - bulk update arrayfield rows postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

How do I update multiple rows

I've a model,

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    colA = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

I want to update all the rows of ModelA, ie for eg:- I want to append `1` in all the rows of column `colA`.

Had it been a normal column, I would have done the following :-

```
ModelA.objects.all().update(colA="foo")
```

How can I bulk update Arrayfield?

Comment: did you try .update(colA=["foo"]) ?  I mean while querying we use a list.. So while updating bulk, the same could be used.. I don know.. But a guess. Please let me know..

Comment: It seems that django documentation says nothing about updating arrays. So my suggestion is to make raw query like: `update ModelA set colA = array_append(colA, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to do currently, I think the best you can do is to do it is to iterate over the models.

```
for model in ModelA.objects.all():
    for val in model_a.colA:
        val = val + 1
    model.save()
```

You can do this as an atomic transaction as well if you wish.. Although it may be worth considering if this field really should be an array field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update) package. Although I'm not sure whether it can handle `ArrayField`

Answer (score -2):

Why not do a database migration? Django's database migration system should allow you to do this easily, I believe.